# How to fix "ORA-01735: Invalid ALTER TABLE option" error in Oracle11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, alter-table

I'm coding a SQL script but, when I compile and try execute with SQL*PLUS, this show mentioned error at beginning of the issue. I'm seeing other related issues but I can't find the solution.

This is for a local server in my Windows 10' computer, running Oracle 11g with SQL*PLUS and XAMPP Server. I've tried on another computer with similar specificatios except specific details.

```
ALTER TABLE ACTORES(
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_actores PRIMARY KEY (Codigo)
);
COMMIT;
ALTER TABLE PERSONAJES(
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_personajes PRIMARY KEY (Codigo),
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk1_personajes FOREIGN KEY (CodigoActor) REFERENCES ACTORES (Codigo),
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk2_personajes FOREIGN KEY (CodigoSuperior) REFERENCES PERSONAJES (Codigo)
);
COMMIT;
ALTER TABLE NAVES(
  ADD CONSTRAINT pk_naves PRIMARY KEY (Codigo)
);
COMMIT;
```

Comment: Which ALTER give you the error? What are the current table definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many parenthesis aren't *healthy*.

```
SQL> create table actores (codigo number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table actores (add constraint pk_actores primary key (codigo));
alter table actores (add constraint pk_actores primary key (codigo))
                    *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01735: invalid ALTER TABLE option


SQL> alter table actores add constraint pk_actores primary key (codigo);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Another table:

```
SQL> create table personajes (codigo number, codigoactor number, codigosuperior number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table personajes add constraint pk_personajes primary key (codigo);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table personajes add constraint fk1_personajes foreign key (codigoactor)
  2    references actores (codigo);

Table altered.

SQL> alter table personajes add constraint fk2_personajes foreign key (codigosuperior)
  2    references personajes (codigo);

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Or, alternatively, several constraints in the same `ALTER TABLE`:

```
SQL> drop table personajes;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table personajes (codigo number, codigoactor number, codigosuperior number);

Table created.

SQL> alter table personajes add
  2    (constraint pk_personajes primary key (codigo),
  3     constraint fk1_personajes foreign key (codigoactor)
  4       references actores (codigo),
  5     constraint fk2_personajes foreign key (codigosuperior)
  6       references personajes (codigo)
  7    );

Table altered.

SQL>
```

Do the same for the rest of your tables/constraints.

P.S. Oh, yes - you don't have to `COMMIT`; `ALTER TABLE` is DDL and implicitly commits any changes.

Comment: Thanks!! I try this option and, later, I explain final results ;)

Comment: That's fine! Thanks a lot Littlefoot